# how to enqueue jQuery v3.6.1 to wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I developed a wordpress plugin and send it to Wordpress plugin directory and it rejected because of : "Including Libraries Already In Core" (jquery)

I enqueued the jQuery v3.6.1 (min) library into my plugin as follows in the version I sent before it was rejected :

```
wp_register_script( 'aicontentgenerator_jquery',$my_plugin_dir.'/js/jquery.min.js' , array(), false, true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'aicontentgenerator_jquery' );
```

Since it was rejected by wordpress, I changed it as follows:

```
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

but after this change was made, my plugin started not working properly.
I did not make any changes to the javascript codes. I think this is because the default jquery version of wordpress is different from the version I have installed.

When I try to run the code, stucking on loading screen and got an error as seen in the picture below.

[image: Stuck on loading screen and got error]

error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
at aicontentgenerator.js?ver=6.1.1:18:7
```

how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the bundled jQuery version for WordPress is in [No Conflict mode](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/), so you can't use the $ directly

You have to use jQuery instead of $ or wrap all your code on something like this

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  // Here you can use $
});
```